# iOS: Is it possible to have a return key on number pad?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

The standard keyboard in iOS does have a return key and there is a delegate method which is called when the user taps the return key.

Is it possible to have a return key on the number pad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to modify the standard number pad. The typical solution is to setup a toolbar with a button and make this view the text field's `inputAccessoryView`. You then call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field when the button is tapped.

Comment: @maddy where will the toolbar show? I have been using a pickerview as the inputAccessoryView in another project, and the pickerview was showing instead of the keyboard of the textview. But I don't need a toolbar with a button instead of keyboard, I would need BOTH showing. Did you ever try it?

Comment: I think you mean you have been using the `UIPickerView` as the `inputView`. The `inputAccessoryView` shows at the top of the keyboard (or `inputView`).

Comment: right, my fault, it was `inputView`. I have been looking at some examples I found on the internet and they encompass a fair amount of code, only to display a return key on top of the number pad. Do you have a link to a short example?

Comment: No I don't. Just create a toolbar, add a button, and setup the button handler to dismiss the keyboard. Assign the toolbar as the text field's `inputAccessoryView`. Not much to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something Like this, you can set you own toolbar position.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if( textField == yourTextField )
    {
        UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButton)],nil];
        textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}
}

- (void)doneButton
{
    [youtTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```